# IndexOutofBounds when using Java's read bytes

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, randomaccessfile

I am using a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in Java 6 but having some strange behavior when reading bytes.

With the following code, where `offset` and `data` are appropriately initialized:

```
int offset;
byte data[];
randFile.readFully(data, offset, data.length);
```

I get  the following stack trace:

```
null
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:355)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:414)
```

BUT, with the same values of `offset` and `data`, the following (seemingly identical) code works fine!

```
randFile.seek(offset);

for (int i = 0; i < (data.length); i += 1) {
    data[i] = randFile.readByte();
}
```

Does anybody have insight into why this might be?

Comment: Which value has `offset`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just guessing, but you probably have an `offset` greater than `0`; if you're reading `data.length` bytes starting from a position greater than 0, you'll pass the end of the `data` array, which may be throwing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So, if you want to read the full array, `offset` variable should be set to `0`. Besides, if you don't want to start from 0, you should read `data.length - offset` bytes.-

```
randFile.readFully(data, offset, data.length - offset);
```

Comment: I think you're correct. I misunderstood the offset parameter as an offset of the file pointer. But the documentation states that data is read from the current file pointer.

Comment: If that was finally the issue, please, consider upvoting/accepting answer, it may useful for other users.

Comment: Had the same exact problem here! Totally misinterpreted the documentation and thought that offset was in the file.

Comment: @wayway Glad it helped :)